# String replace method doesn't work

Tags: java, replace

I try to replace characters in expression with float values. In the first case everything is ok, in the second nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
expr = expressions.get(i)[0];
for (int j = 0; j < valsListArray.length; j++) {
    String selection = (String) valsListArray[j].getSelectedItem(); 
    Float valueFloat = segmentAreas.get(j);                      
    String valueString = "" + valueFloat;
    expr = expr.replace(selection, valueString);
}
for (int jj = 0; jj < koefsLabelsArray.size(); jj++) {
    String selection1 = (String) koefsLabelsArray.get(jj).getText();                
    String valueString1 = valsOfKoefs.get(jj).getText();
    expr = expr.replace(selection1, valueString1); //here nothing happens
    System.out.println(expr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
expr = expr.replace(valueString1, selection1);
```

you should use  the following I guess:

```
expr = expr.replace(selection1, valueString1);
```

Comment: I've made it... It was not right code. But replacement not happens

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

You might be wanting to call `replaceAll` method rather than `replace`. Try

`expr = expr.replaceAll(selection1, valueString1);`

---

Edit:

This works properly for me, and since I don't have an idea about your variables, maybe the issue lies there?

```
   String var = "abcbdbebfb";
    float f = 1.0f;
    String toFind = "b";
    var = var.replaceAll(toFind,(String.valueOf(f)));
    System.out.println(var);
```

Output:

```
a1.0c1.0d1.0e1.0f1.0
```

Comment: I understand what is old and whaat is new. It's 2 different cases. In the first I replace characters to variables of expression, in the second I replace characters to coefficients and get them from another place.

Comment: In the beggining i work only with variables and add them to the expression and then do the same with coefficients to the common expression

Comment: Sorry, copied the old code.... Changes are made but it doesn't work still

Comment: This is not the correct JavaDoc nor the correct method. He is using replace(String, String) and not replace(char, char)!

Comment: @GuillaumePolet You are right. My bad. Sorry about that. Thanks for pointing it out. :-)

Comment: @Den-Ben please see the edits. :-)

Comment: Did you try some debugging? And you are saying `float` values, but in the second case, your variable is still `String`.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Both arguments take right values, but expression does not change...  I meant variables are counted like float further (it's does not metter)

Comment: (a+b)*k. "a" and "b"  replaced by for example 2.51 and 6.355 at the first part. At the second part arguments are string, selection = k, valueString = 5. After replace string expr still without changes: (2.51+6.355)*k

Comment: Please see the edits. :-) replaceAll should do your job. :-)

Comment: I've tried to use replaceAll. The situation is the same

Comment: http://ideone.com/ErLeC I ran a small dummy for the equation you gave. Works fine mate.

Answer (score 0):

So I understood that problem appeared because of I got the first string "selection1" from JLabel (but I cant understand why), in the other case all is ok.